# Java - Printing a null string in my Pagination list

Tags: java, arrays

I have this matrix socios, which has information about each associate. The pesquisarSocioPorNif method returns the line in which the input has been found. The point is to completely erase all data from that associate, so I have to delete the whole line. I tried to delete it by overlapping, and it works! Except when I try to list it, which lists me a null string. Here are both of my methods:

DELETE METHOD:

```
 public static String[][] alterarDadosSocios(String[][] socios, int nSocios, String nif) {
    int optionAlt;
    Scanner opAlt = new Scanner(System.in);
    int indice = pesquisarSocioPorNif(nif, nSocios, socios);
    if (indice != -1) {
        do {
            optionAlt = menuAlt();
            switch (optionAlt) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Introduza o novo nome. Ex: Rui Filipe.. ");
                    socios[indice][1] = opAlt.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Nome alterado com sucesso.");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Introduza a nova data. (Dia/Mes/Ano), Ex: 12/05/1998");
                    socios[indice][2] = opAlt.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Data alterada com sucesso.");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Operação interrompida.");
                    break;
            }
        } while (optionAlt != 0);
    } else {
        System.out.println("NIF não encontrado. Introduza um NIF válido.");
    }

    return socios;
}
```

LIST METHOD:

```
    public static void listarComPaginacao(String[][] socios, int nSocios) {
    int contPaginas = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nSocios; i++) {
        if (i % MAX_LINHAS_PAGINA == 0) {
            if (contPaginas > 0) {
                pausa();
            }
            contPaginas++;
            System.out.println("\nPÁGINA: " + contPaginas);
            cabecalho();
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < N_CAMPOS_INFO; j++) {
                System.out.print(socios[i][j] + " | ");
        }
    }
}
```

WHICH OUTPUTS:

```
PÁGINA: 1
NIF --------- NOME -------------------- DATA DE NASCIMENTO ---------- SEXO
=========================================================================================

111111111 | Rui Filipe Monteiro Almeida | 12/06/1998 | masculino | 
222222222 | Jose Alameda Duarte dos Santos | 12/10/1990 | masculino | 
333333333 | Amadeus Antunes Roberoso Tuberculo | 17/03/2000 | masculino | 
123485748 | Romeu Julieta Runescape World | 18/06/2004 | masculino | 
678378589 | Antonieta Julia Mosquito | 20/15/1990 | feminino | 

Para continuar digite ENTER



PÁGINA: 2
NIF --------- NOME -------------------- DATA DE NASCIMENTO ---------- SEXO
=========================================================================================

889589488 | LEEROY JENKINS CHUMPS UP LETS DO THIS | 27/06/1994 | feminino |
```

BUT AFTER DELETING ASSOCIATE 222222222:

```
PÁGINA: 1
NIF --------- NOME -------------------- DATA DE NASCIMENTO ---------- SEXO
=========================================================================================

111111111 | Rui Filipe Monteiro Almeida | 12/06/1998 | masculino | 
333333333 | Amadeus Antunes Roberoso Tuberculo | 17/03/2000 | masculino | 
123485748 | Romeu Julieta Runescape World | 18/06/2004 | masculino | 
678378589 | Antonieta Julia Mosquito | 20/15/1990 | feminino | 
889589488 | LEEROY JENKINS CHUMPS UP LETS DO THIS | 27/06/1994 | feminino | 

Para continuar digite ENTER



PÁGINA: 2
NIF --------- NOME -------------------- DATA DE NASCIMENTO ---------- SEXO
=========================================================================================

null | null | null | null |
```

How do I keep that null from being listed?

If you didn't understand something because of the language barrier, I'll translate everything to english x) I'm running a bit short on time as I'm posting this. I need this to be able to do this for my final project for college first year, so I can't use any java method beyond those I create myself.

If you could give me a hand on this, I'd appreciate it a lot, thanks for your time if you read this far! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use an ArrayList instead of an array, you can use a delete method to delete the row, and everything will display cleanly. If you must us an array, then you can either delete the row manually (by constructing a new array of 1 less row, and copying the old to it), or make sure that your output code skips any rows with a null value in it.